# How to solve: the sum of $t_5$ and $t_{10}$ of a sequence is $10$, which is equal to $t_{16}$. What is $t_{33}$?

Tags: arithmetic

This is using arithmetic sequences.

The sum of $t_5$ and $t_{10}$ of a sequence is $10$, which is equal to $t_{16}$. What is $t_{33}$?

($t$ stands for term in the sequence)

Comment: If $t_1,d$ be the first term and common difference respectively,  what is the $n$th term $t_n$

Comment: Tell us what you tried and where you got stuck. This to avoid downvotes and closing.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This is one of those times where starting to count at  $0$ instead of $1$ is objectively better, in my opinion. I know many don't in introductory arithmetic sequences, and I find that a shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the first term be a and difference be d .

$t_5+t_{10}=10$

$(a+4d)+(a+9d)=10$ -------- (1)

$t_{16}=10$

$(a+15d)=10$ -------- (2)

Multiply equation (2) by $2$.

$2a+30d=20$ --------- (3)

Subtract equation (1) from (3).

Therefore $d=\frac{10}{17}$.

Put this value in any of the above equation to find $a$.

Then use the formula $t_n= a+(n-1)d$ to find $t_{33}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $t_n=nd+a$ for some constants $a$ and $d$. You are given
$$ t_5+t_{10}=10$$
and 
$$t_{16}=10 $$
which are two linear equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $d$.

Comment: How would I combine t5 and t10 into one equation so I can have one equation for them and one equation for t16 so I can then rearrange and solve?